# many to many laravel get values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

in user class model , i have this

```
    public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project');
}
```

in project class model i have this :

```
    public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

in my projectController i have this :

```
    public function index()
{
    $TeamLeader = array();
    $posts = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->with('users')->paginate(5); 
    return view('Projects.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

in my view i have this for each :

```
                    @foreach ($posts as $post)
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
                        <td href="{{ route('Projects.show', $post->project_id ) }}">{{ $post->project_id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $post->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $post->description }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $post->created_at }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->name}}</td>
                        <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#show" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p></td>
                        <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
```

my problem is , in my view i can not get the users name ,  the realation is many-to-many  but  iam not getting the names of the users who are involved in the project , the database structure is as you can imagine :

Users has   id , name , ......

Projects has id , name , location , user_id , .....

sorry to not mention that earlier but i have this common table also :

```
        Schema::create('project_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your tables design is not many to many, It's one to many [User has many Project]
if you want to make many to many relation must make a middle table (pivot table)

take a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
[This is helpful](https://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/introducing-laravel-many-to-many-relations/)

---

Add this to your migrations

```
Schema::create('project_user', function(Blueprint $table)
  {
      $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
      $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
            ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

      $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
      $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')
            ->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');

      $table->timestamps();
  });
```

`project_user` table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and contains the user_id and project_id columns
Then remove user_id column from your projects table

Finally yo can access the name of users like

```
$project->users[0]->name
$project->users[0]->name
```

Comment: i updated my code , i still do not  understand where to use this line  : 
Table => pivot_users_projects [user_id, project_id]  ????  how i can get the name of the user  when i am quering the projects table ??

Comment: "Table => pivot_users_projects [user_id, project_id]" this is not code, I mean you must create a pivot table.  $project->users is an array of Users